# Unable to create R2DBC connection factory for mysql through auto configuration unless change scope of another dependency to runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

```
java.version=17
spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc=3.1.1
spring-boot-starter-webflux=3.1.1
```

I have specified the following in application.properties to be picked up by the auto configuration.

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:pool:mysql://localhost:3306/airportdb
spring.r2dbc.username=admin
spring.r2dbc.password=REDACTED
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

When I start the Spring boot application I get the following exception at the bottom of the log.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={database=airportdb, host=localhost, driver=mysql, password=REDACTED, protocol=, port=3306, user=admin}}'. Available drivers: [ pool ]
```

Now, I have been able to solve this exception by adding this snippet to my pom.xml in the dependencies section.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT- This is already a part of my effective pom, I'm not adding it new, just changing it's scope which resolves my issue.**

As soon as I add this to my pom, I'm able to launch the app and it works flawlessly but for the life of me I can't understand what the original problem was and how just changing the scope of this dependency which has been pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` solves it. Thanks.

Comment: Is mysql actually being *used* now? (As opposed to H2) I thought it didn't support r2dbc yet

Comment: The effective pom has this driver r2dbc-mysql with groupId io.asyncer. My configuration is for my local mysql db as well, although I haven't performed a CRUD operation yet.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether that was a yes or no. I'm guessing "no" so far...

Comment: I was just able to run a fetchById query from a ReactiveCrudRepository on mysql's airport sample db's booking table. At least reactive reads are supported in 2023.

Comment: That's good, try a save and check that a write has occurred in the mysql table